# No matching hardware interface found for 'hardware_interface/JointStateInterface' while loading interfaces

Tags: ros, urdf, ros-melodic, transmission

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot defined in a URDF file that I want to use in gazebo with ros-control.

The robot has multiple non-fixed joints, but **I only want to control the wheels.** The other non-fixed joints should move freely according to the movement of the wheels. For the wheels I need to write a transmission like so:

```
<transmission name="${prefix}_wheel_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <actuator name="${prefix}_wheel_motor">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
    <joint name="${prefix}_wheel_joint">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
</transmission>
```

My question is, how do I write a transmission for the other non-fixed joints so that their state is published by the `JointStateController`? I tried the following:

```
<transmission name="${prefix}_something_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <actuator name="${prefix}_something_motor">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
    <joint name="${prefix}_something_joint">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/JointStateInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
</transmission>
```

But it results in the error `No matching hardware interface found for 'hardware_interface/JointStateInterface' while loading interfaces for something_joint`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372985/no-matching-hardware-interface-found-for-%27hardware_interface/jointstateinterface%27-while-loading-interfaces/) by [tirafesi](https://answers.ros.org/users/64280/tirafesi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But it results in the error `No matching hardware interface found for 'hardware_interface/JointStateInterface' while loading interfaces for something_joint`.

that's because `hardware_interface/JointStateInterface` is not a valid value for the `hardwareInterface` element.

It should be one of

- `hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface`
- `hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface` or
- `hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface`

Documentation is not very clear on this, I admit.

(would be a great opportunity to contribute)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tirafesi](https://answers.ros.org/users/64280/tirafesi/) on 2021-03-01**:
I see. So what should I do regarding the non-fixed joints that i do NOT want to control? Use `PositionJointInterface`? But if I use that, then it complaints about missing PID coefficients - which are useless to me since I don't want to control the joint. Should I just set those to random values in order to fix the error message?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-01**:
I don't know right now.

That would also seem to be a different question.

I merely explained why you get that error.

I recommend you post your follow-up issues as a separate question, and accept the answer to this one.